# image is not being resizing into bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel which is working fine in 100 % width but I need to reduce height and width of it

my code is

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width:1000px;height:360px;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="display: none;">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/9.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="max-width:1000px;height:360px;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="max-width:1000px;height:360px;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="New York" style="max-width:1000px;height:360px;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
```

now I am getting my desire height but image is not stretching into width  given as you can see in this screen shot  it is giving me such result

https://screenshots.firefox.com/IjKqguGjIUp4pgY0/localhost

Comment: You're happy to have your images stretch/warp, right? Either you have to use images with a bigger dimensions than the slider or your images will be stretched/warped.

Comment: sir idk I just want image should be clear on my desire dimentions

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `100%` width for your images. Update your code like below.

```
<img src="images/9.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%; max-width:1000px;height:360px;">
```

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/gKhFrMuQLuIaemEt/localhost   can this be resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width:
>   100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales
>   with the parent element.

You can use .img-fluid like:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

Above is from [Bootstrap Documentation v4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)